# Python: how to print the first element of a dictionary and position of the second?

Tags: python, dictionary

I just started dictionaries on my class today, now I'm trying to create a cipher based on the keypad of a phone. I have, for example, this dictionary:

```
2:['a','b','c']
```

Now, if I wanted to encrypt for example, a, the output would be 21, the two from the dictionary and 1 from the position of a inside it, but I don't really know how to do it. Here's what I've tried so far but isn't working.

```
def phoneCipher(string):
    cipher = ''
    keypad = {'2':['a','b','c'],'3':['d','e','f'],'4':['g','h','i'],'5':['j','k','l'],'6' : ['m','n','o'],
              '7':['p','q','r','s'],'8':['t','u','v'],'9':['w','x','y','z']}
    for i in string:
        if i in keypad:
            position = keypad.find(i)
            cipher = keypad[i] + position
    return cipher
```

Comment: you're using the dictionary backwards. `if i in keypad` will tell you if `i` is a key, not in one of the values. And `keypad[i]` is the list of letters in that dictionary element.

Comment: so I should write keypad in i instead?

Comment: No, you have to search the dictionary for a key where `i in keypad[key]`

Comment: I suggest creating an inverted dictionary, e.g. `'a': '21', 'b': '22', ...`

Comment: I thougt I could use it to find the letter in the dictionary

Comment: There are no built-in functions that search dictionary values, just keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it that way around, then as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) say's when you check if `i in keypad` its checking the keys of the dictionary, i.e. the number values. So that'll never match.
Also seems like you want to get the cipher for each character in the string, thus two nest loops are needed.
I think this works how you wanted.

```
def phoneCipher(string):
    cipher = ''
    keypad = {'2':['a','b','c'],'3':['d','e','f'],'4':['g','h','i'],'5':['j','k','l'],'6' : ['m','n','o'],
              '7':['p','q','r','s'],'8':['t','u','v'],'9':['w','x','y','z']}
    for i in string:
        for key in keypad:
            if i in keypad[key]:
                #position = keypad[key].index(i) # note its index not find, but we don't actually need it
                cipher += key
    return cipher
```

Although it terribly inefficient, i'd suggest twisting your dictionary on its head, so it is letters to numbers rather than numbers to letters.

so maybe:

```
def phoneCipher2(string):
    cipher = ''
    keypad = {'a':'2','b':'2','c':'2',
    'd':'3','e':'3','f':'3',
    'g':'4','h':'4','i':'4',
    'j':'5','k':'5','l':'5',
    'm':'6','n':'6','o':'6',
    'p':'7','q':'7','r':'7','s':'7',
    't':'8','u':'8','v':'8',
    'w':'9','x':'9','y':'9','z':'9',}
    for i in string:
        cipher += keypad[i]
    return cipher
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def phoneCipher(string):
    cipher = ''
    keypad = {'2':['a','b','c'],'3':['d','e','f'],'4':['g','h','i'],'5':['j','k','l'],'6' : ['m','n','o'],
              '7':['p','q','r','s'],'8':['t','u','v'],'9':['w','x','y','z']}
    
    for i in string:
      for key in keypad:
        if i in keypad[key]:
          cipher += key
          continue
    
    return cipher

phoneCipher("ishan")
```

Output -

```
47426
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works really well, although I can't use continue yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then replace it with break. Both would have the same results.

Comment: If you are new to Python, I'll suggest looking into `itertools`. It's very helpful for such problems.

Comment: I just started a few months ago but my teacher is really slow. I'll look into it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic options you can do. One is to iterate each `list` in the `dict` and then iterate the `list` and see if the value is in there. The other is to have a forward and a reverse `dict`. This takes up more memory but is much faster.

**Option 1** Iterate `list` in `dict`

```
def phoneCipher(string):
    cipher = ''
    keypad = {'2': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '3': ['d', 'e', 'f'], '4': ['g', 'h', 'i'],
              '5': ['j', 'k', 'l'], '6': ['m', 'n', 'o'], '7': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
              '8': ['t', 'u', 'v'], '9': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}

    for c in string:
        for number, letters in keypad.items():
            if c in letters:
                cipher += number + str(letters.index(c))
    return cipher
```

**Option 2** Use reverse lookup `dict`

```
keypad = {'2': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '3': ['d', 'e', 'f'], '4': ['g', 'h', 'i'],
          '5': ['j', 'k', 'l'], '6': ['m', 'n', 'o'], '7': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
          '8': ['t', 'u', 'v'], '9': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']}

# Creating a reverse dict should be done only once and saved for future/repeated use
reverse_lookup = dict()

for number, letters in keypad.items():
    for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
        reverse_lookup[letter] = number + str(index)


def phoneCipher(string):
    return ''.join(map(lambda char: reverse_lookup[char], string))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this one works very good but as dumb as it sounds, we're not allowed to use .index or reverse yet.

Comment: If I wanted to do it the other way around, inputting the numbers and getting back the letters, is there a way to do it without inverting the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, you would take the input say `21` and split it into individual characters with `input.split('')`. Then iterate each character with `dict[char1][int(char2)]`. `char1` would return the `list` containing the letters and then `char2` would be the index of the letter in that `list`. Make sure to cast `char2` to an `int` cause lists only work on `int`.